# Qfield 2.5.1 GNSS Bluetooth Connection Fail

Tags: gps

As of the update to 2.5.1, I am no longer able to connect to my GNSS via Bluetooth and am presented with the following error "Scanning failed: Classic discovery cannot be enabled". The issue appears to be limited to Qfield as I am still able to connect using SWMaps.
Phone:Pixel 6A
GNSS: Sparkfun Facet L band